# How to get System date formate

Tags: vue.js, localization, date-format, globalization

I have an application in Vuejs (Typescript) that get date from User, I am facing two issues for the time being.

- Every time the User enter date of birth system decreases one.
- If user enter 03/05/1981 and the System date formate is MM/dd/yyyy it store 5th of March.

I can't tell every person to change format to dd/MM/yyyy, or is there a way around.

Thanks

Comment: use a date-picker instead of letting the user enter the date ? I'm not sure what do you mean by _system decreases one_.

Answer (score 0):

By the details you have provided I assume everything happens in the browser.

Please check your browser localization settings even if your computer localization is setup as US if the browser has a different setting then it will be overwritten.

If you are sending the information to a different server please check how are you formatting the date in your request and which are the server side settings about localization.

Hope this helps.